# Vaadin 8 non-modal Window CloseListener - close by a click outside it

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I have a non-modal `Window` in the application, being open on part of the browser view.

```
setModal(false);
```

It's content is a `HorizontalLayout` - not sure whether this matters.

I'm looking to do certain things when this window closes for any reason. So for this, I added to it a [`CloseListener`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.CloseListener.html):

```
addCloseListener(e -> System.out.println("closing the window _____________________"));
```

this `CloseListener` isn't running when the `Window` is closed by a click outside it, and this is the only case it's missing AFAIS. I saw [How to close a Vaadin subwindow on mouseclick outside of the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326548/how-to-close-a-vaadin-subwindow-on-mouseclick-outside-of-the-window) Is there an easier way to fix this? 
Fine solution, but too lengthy for the outcome in our application.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a layoutclicklistener or any sort of click listeners to the view that the window appears in?

addCloseListener only fires when the window is closed. It doesn't cause the window to close itself.

`component.addClickListener(e -> {
if(getUI().getWindows().contains(myWindow)
//logic goes here (remove/hide window)
});`

refer to https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/event/LayoutEvents.LayoutClickNotifier.html#addLayoutClickListener-com.vaadin.event.LayoutEvents.LayoutClickListener-